# Error when uploading a directory to Dropbox including all files and sub-directories with Dropbox Python API

Tags: python, python-2.7, dropbox, dropbox-api

I’m trying to upload a directory to Dropbox along with all its files
including any sub-directories and its files using the Dropbox Python API.

Files can be uploaded alright and it can create new Dropbox folders. I wonder if anyone has a solution for this.

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "dir_2_dropbox.py", line 27, in 
>       client.put_file(dropbox_path, f)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/dropbox/client.py", line 377, in put_file
>       return self.rest_client.PUT(url, file_obj, headers)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 321, in PUT
>       return cls.IMPL.PUT(*n, **kw)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 258, in PUT
>       return self.request("PUT", url, body=body, headers=headers, raw_response=raw_response)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/dropbox/rest.py", line 227, in request
>       raise ErrorResponse(r, r.read())
>   dropbox.rest.ErrorResponse: [400] u'The file /mobistudios/.DS_Store is on the ignored file list, so it was not saved.'

```
local_dir = ('/users/ninekay/desktop/scripts')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_dir):

    for filename in files:

        local_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

        relative_path = os.path.relpath(local_path, local_dir)
        dropbox_path = os.path.join(‘/mobistudios’, relative_path)

        with open(local_path, 'rb') as f:
            client.put_file(dropbox_path, f)
```

Why do I have this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: Your error message is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, have updated with full error message.

Comment: You are trying to upload a .DS_Store file, which dropbox doesn't allow.
Exclude that from your list of files to upload.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204688799-Upload-a-directory-including-all-its-files-and-sub-directories ]

Comment: That was it. Working fine now without those incompatible files. Thanks to every one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Ignored files section from [Dropbox’s help center](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/145).

You could then exclude such files when sync’ing. I add the `IGNORED_FILES` variable to account for such files and a `is_ignored` function to check whether files will cause that error before ‘putting’ them.

```
IGNORED_FILES = ['desktop.ini', 'thumbs.db', '.ds_store',
                         'icon\r', '.dropbox', '.dropbox.attr']
def is_ignored(filename):
    filename_lower = filename.lower()
    for ignored_file in IGNORED_FILES:
        if ignored_file in filename_lower:
            return True
    return False


local_dir = ('/users/ninekay/desktop/scripts')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_dir):

for filename in files:
    if is_ignored(filename):
        continue

    local_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
    relative_path = os.path.relpath(local_path, local_dir)
    dropbox_path = os.path.join(‘/mobistudios’, relative_path)


    with open(local_path, 'rb') as f:
        client.put_file(dropbox_path, f)
```